# Visual Studio 2012 Express - Slider control missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

It seems that My Visual Studio 2012 Express is missing the slider control.
I've looked in the Toolbox but couldn't find it there, although all other controls are listed.

After some research I reset the Toolbox by right-clicking it and choosing "Show all" and "Reset Toolbox", but nothing changed. Also, I clicked on "Choose Items" in the "All Windows Forms" section and in the filter, I typed "sl" and no components were shown.

On MSDN, I found articles about editing the slider control, so I'm sure it exists, but am I wrong?

Comment: It's called a Slider control in WPF, a TrackBar control in WinForms, and either of the above in Win32. Easiest to just look at the little pictures. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its called 'Trackbar' in Visual Studio 2012 Express - look for that